# Is it possible to give a complex structure on two dimensional cone?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $G$ be group of $n^{th}$ roots of unity. Assume that $G=<\alpha>$, where $\alpha ^n=1$.
Now we define a group action, $G$ act on $\mathbb{C}$, by $(x,z)\mapsto xz$. The Quotient space $\mathbb{C}/G$ is homeomorphic to a cone, that is $\mathbb{C}/G$ is homeomorphic to cone of $S^1 \times [0,\infty)$. The open sets of the $\mathbb{C}/G$ is $\hat{U}=\{Gz : z \in U\}$, where $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{C}$. So, one can give an complex chart $\phi :\hat{U}\rightarrow U$, by $\phi(Gz)=z$.

My Question, is it possible  to give a complex structure $\mathbb{C}/G$? Even it is not a smooth manifolds, I also confused where I was wrong to define the complex charts on $\mathbb{C}/G$.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand that the quotient space is homeomorphic to the plane?

Comment: No no, quotient space is homeomorphic to a cone.

Comment: Yes, and the cone is homeomorphic to the plane.

Comment: Here I want give a complex structure on the cone. Yes they are homeomorphic but I can give complex structure on plane.

Comment: Do you understand what it means to give a complex structure to a topological space? Do you understand that if you give a complex structure to a space $X$ you automatically give a complex structure to all spaces homeomorphic to $X$?

Comment: Complex structure on connected two manifold mean I can give a complex a complex atlas on $X$ such that transition maps are biholomorphic. But I do not know how this biholomorphicity invariant under homeomorphism.

Comment: Ok, your definition of a complex structure is not quite right, but it is close enough. Suppose that $(X, \tau)$ is a topological manifold of dimension $2n$ and $\tau$ is a maximal holomorphic atlas on $X$. Suppose that $Y$ is another topological space and $f: Y\to X$ is a homeomorphism. Then define the holomorphic atlas $\sigma$ on $Y$ as the collection of compositions $\psi=\varphi\circ f$, where $\varphi: U\to C^n$ are charts in $\tau$. The domain of $\psi$ is the open subset $V:= f^{-1}(U)\subset Y$. Now, check that $\sigma$ is indeed a holomorphic atlas on $Y$.

Comment: Yes, new holomorphic atlas $\psi_1 o \psi_2 ^{-1}=\phi_1 o f o(\phi_2 o f)^{-1}=\phi_1 o \phi_2 ^{-1}$, where $\phi_1, \phi_2$ are two charts in $X$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thanks! Then cone is a Riemann Surface right?

Comment: A meaningful statement would be that every cone admits a complex structure, or can be equipped with a Riemann surface structure.